# Use site URL in build event

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, build

I wrote a powershell script that associates a workflow with a site and I want to call it in the post-build event of the workflow project in visual studio.

How do I get the "Site URL" field in the project properties to use as a macro variable in the post-build event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$(SharePointSiteUrl)` variable in the post-build event. `$(SharePointSiteUrl)`is an extra variable that is available for SharePoint projects.

> $(SharePointSiteUrl) is the URL you’ve selected in the properties of
>   the SharePoint project.
>
> $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).wsp is the name of the solution package
>   file.
>
> For flexibility, instead of using hard-coded strings in the
>   Pre-deployment Command Line and Post-deployment Command Line boxes on
>   the SharePoint Properties page, you can use the SharePoint properties
>   as arguments. For example, instead of specifying a specific URL string
>   for the SharePoint site, you can instead use $(SharePointSiteUrl).

Here is the complete list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee696754%28VS.100%29.aspx